# Porque no se resetea el puntero

Tags: python

tengo un script de python con 2 funciones y la primera va por un array de numeros pasando cada numero a la segunda función si ese numero es '3' resetea el puntero del array a 0, el problema es que eso no ocurre:

```
Ptr = 0
Ptr2 = 0

def Segunda(num:int):
    global Ptr
    global Ptr2
    if num == 3:
        Ptr = 0
        Ptr2 += 1
    else: print(num)

def Primera():
    global Ptr
    global Ptr2
    Nums= [1,2,3]
    if Ptr2 != 3:
        for _ in range(len(Nums)):
            Segunda(Nums[Ptr])
            Ptr+=1
Primera()
```

esto deberia imprimir:

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

pero devuelve:

```
1
2
```

No se cual es el problema, deberia resetear `ptr` a '0' y empezar desde `Nums[ptr]`

Comment: eso nunca va a pasar y no porque tu variable `Ptr` no se resetee (que si lo hace) sino por que el ciclo esta limitado a 3 iteraciones, la primera y la segunda iteración se imprime normal ya que el número no es `3`, pero la tercera no se imprime ya que si es `3` y ahí termina el ciclo ya que estas iterando en el rango de la longitud de la lista, que es 3, osea solo haces 3 iteraciones de las cuales 2 son impresas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que estas utilizando un `if` en `if Ptr2 != 3:` esto sólo se evalúa una vez, esta línea no vuelve a ejecutarse por lo que tu `for` solo se ejecuta una vez

Si deseas que tu `for` siga imprimiendo valores "x" cantidad de veces (En tu caso 3) entonces puedes utilizar un `while`

Otro problema es que en tu `for` estás utilizando `_` para iterar y adentro del `for` incrementas `Ptr` podrías utilizar directamente `Ptr` para iterar

Te dejo el código funcionando:

```
Ptr = 0
Ptr2 = 0

def Segunda(num:int):
    global Ptr
    global Ptr2
    if num == 3:
        Ptr = 0
        Ptr2 += 1
    else: print(num)

def Primera():
    global Ptr
    global Ptr2
    Nums= [1,2,3]
    while Ptr2 != 3:
      for Ptr in range(len(Nums)):
        Segunda(Nums[Ptr])


Primera()
```

Salida

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
```